# Failed to resolve for reference Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions - Metadata generation failed

Tags: c#, azure, msbuild, azure-functions

Had to pick up a bit of work from another developer so just trying to wrap my head round it all!

But I'm having issues building an Azure Functions project and continuously getting a error coming form `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets` , specifically unable to resolve a reference to `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions`.

So far I have attempted re-installing the Nuget Package, Re-Starting Visual Studio, my machine yada-yada.

I would welcome any suggestions and appreciate your time!

Full Error Below

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
   at Mono.Cecil.DefaultAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Resolve(TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve()
   at MakeFunctionJson.AttributeExtensions.IsWebJobsAttribute(CustomAttribute attribute)
   at MakeFunctionJson.ParameterInfoExtensions.<>c.<IsWebJobSdkTriggerParameter>b__0_0(CustomAttribute a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at MakeFunctionJson.ParameterInfoExtensions.IsWebJobSdkTriggerParameter(ParameterDefinition parameterInfo)
   at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.<>c.<HasTriggerAttribute>b__4_0(ParameterDefinition p)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.HasTriggerAttribute(MethodDefinition method)
   at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.HasValidWebJobSdkTriggerAttribute(MethodDefinition method)
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.GenerateFunctions(IEnumerable`1 types)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons()
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun()
Error generating functions metadata
    Panmure.RiskMI.DataCollector.Functions
```

Comment: I am dealing with the same thing right now. I'll let you know if I have any breakthroughs. For me I get the error every other time I try to run the project.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I saw a message when running the project saying "the extensionsmetadatagenerator package was not imported correctly" Try adding the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator nuget package to your project. It is suppose to be loaded as a dependency of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package, But I didn't see it in my project dependencies list. This worked for me.

Comment: This happens when you have a version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions higher then 3.1.1, while using .NETCore3.1.
The higher versions are for .NET6, however they don't return a direct error, but won't load their dependencies/NuGet packages.
Your answer works, but it I prefer to downgrade Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to 3.1.1.

Comment: @Sam answer is the right one for me too. Strange it didn't stop me from installing a NuGet package that clearly says net6.0 under Dependencies.

Comment: Right, but downgrading dot net isn't always an option.

Answer (score 6):

Or you can just update to

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

If you are not on 3.1

Comment: This wasn't enough for me, I was already on this when I started getting this error. Adding the above-mentioned metadata generator package fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post. I am using JetBrain Rider on a Mac. The only way I've gotten around this is to reinstall .Net 5 even though I am building the Function in .Net 6. Any updates that happen to .net 6 is requiring me to reinstall .net 5.

Comment: Exactly the same for me with Rider on macOS. It happened when I installed .NET6, I had to install .NET5 again to make it work. And it happened now once again when I installed .NET7, same error and I had to install .NET5 (now out of support) and my .NET7 v4 Azure Functions now works.

Comment: Same here. I installed .net 8 and I couldn't build my project. After re-installing .net 5 my issue was gone.